# JQuery Offset Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a navigation menu for a website. When the user scrolls past the point 497px it needs to change colour. I have wrote this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function checkOffset() {
      var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
      console.log(offset);
        if(offset > 497){
          $("#fixedBar").animate({backgroundColor: '#1B1B1B'}, 1000);
          $("#fixedBar nav a").animate({color: '#FFF'}, 1000);
        }else{
          $("#fixedBar").animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 1000);
          $("nav a").animate({color: '#1B1B1B'}, 1000);

        }
      }
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
      checkOffset();
     });

  });
```

If I refresh the page and it is past that point then it indeed changes, however if I simply scroll past that point then it doesn't change. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your script probably works. But since you are animating on every scroll. there is a chance of having consecutive animation cycles. My suggestion is to first change the `animate` to `css` method temporarily and see if it works. If it does then make sure you call `stop()` before animation, refer URL https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Then, let me add this as answer. Let this be useful for others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script probably works.

But since you are animating on every scroll. there is a chance of having consecutive animation cycles.

Possible solutions would be (Any one of these points),

1. To use either `css` method rather than `animate`
2. Executing `stop()` before animating should help.
3. Check the existing color value before executing the `animate` method

To know more about [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To use `.animate()` with colors, you will need jQueryUI. So, add the framework to your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js""></script>
```

Then, try it again (I modified a little your current code):

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function() { 
        checkOffset();
    });
});

function checkOffset() {
    var $target = $('#fixedBar');
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(offset);
    if(offset >= 10){
        $target.stop(true, false).animate({ 'background-color': 'green'}, 1000);
        //$("#fixedBar nav a").animate({color: '#FFF'}, 1000);
    }
    else if( offset < 10 ){
        $target.stop(true, false).animate({ 'background-color': 'blue' }, 1000);
        //$("nav a").animate({color: '#1B1B1B'}, 1000);
    }
}
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/cgk25m4j/).

Answer (score 0):

You should call checkOffset(); one more time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function checkOffset() {
        var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(offset);
        if(offset > 497){
            $("#fixedBar").animate({backgroundColor: '#1B1B1B'}, 1000);
            $("#fixedBar nav a").animate({color: '#FFF'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#fixedBar").animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 1000);
            $("nav a").animate({color: '#1B1B1B'}, 1000);  
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        checkOffset();
    });

    checkOffset(); // <-- HERE

});
```